# Camera for Spotlight

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, viewport

I have two orthographic cameras. The first one is for the main display and the other one is used for a spotlight effect.

What I want is, if I move the second camera (spotlight), I want the view port rect to be normalized as well. Right now, if I move the second camera's Transform, it looks at the camera's direction but the display is not moving.

So, if the display is at the bottom-right corner, and I move the camera at the top-left corner, I want to display the camera at the top-left corner as well instead of displaying it at the bottom-right corner.

Also, I'm building it on iPad.

[image]

Comment: Such questions are absolutely fine here @ShivanRaptor and actively answered as well. Dzep, could you perhaps illustrate what you're currently seeing and what you want to have instead. And perhaps any script or view or your hierarchy would help as well.

Comment: Thanks! I edited my post, see the picture. If I make the second camera, smaller, it fits all of the contents so modifying the view port rect will help me solve the problem.